# The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large without using datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf, primefaces, google-cloud-sql

com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RequestTooLargeException: The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large.

```
public static List<Area> readAreas(URL url) {
    List<Area> areas = new ArrayList<Area>();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(url.toURI())));
        String row;
        while ((row = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (row.contains(SEARCHED_ROW)) {
                //get the part after "c"
                String coord[] = (row.split("c"));
                String startCoordM = ((coord[0].trim()).split(" "))[1];
                String curvesCoord= coord[1];

                Area area = new Area();
                area.mPoint= Point.toStartPoint(Point.readPoints(startCoordM));
                area.curves = Curve.readCurves (curvesCoord);
                areas.add(area);
            }
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return areas;
}
```

This method runs without any errors but when I log out and log in to the same page of my web application this method runs again and again without problem but then this exception is thrown. I'm using google app engine 1.8.1 with jsf2 and primefaces 3.5. This method is invoked from managed bean :

```
public MapMB () {
    eps = EPDAO.getEPList();
    populateAdvancedModel(eps);
    drawPolilines();
}

void drawPolilines() {
    List<Area> areas = Area.readAreas(getFacesContext().getClass().getResource("/map-inksc.svg") );

    for (Area area : areas) {

        List<Curve> curves = area.getCurves();
        Point endPoint = area.getmPoint();

        Polyline polyline = new Polyline();
        polyline.setStrokeWeight(1);  
        polyline.setStrokeColor("#FF0000");  
        polyline.setStrokeOpacity(1);

        for (Curve curve : curves) {
            polyline.getPaths().add( new LatLng(endPoint.getY(),endPoint.getX()) );
            // curve start point is the end point of previous curve (endPoint.getX(),endPoint.getY() )
            double step = 0.01;
            for (double t=0;t<= 1;t=t+step) {
                double x = getCoordFromCurve(endPoint.getX(), endPoint.getX() + curve.getP1().getX(),endPoint.getX() + curve.getP2().getX(),endPoint.getX() + curve.getP3().getX(), t);
                double y = getCoordFromCurve(endPoint.getY(), endPoint.getY() + curve.getP1().getY(),endPoint.getY() + curve.getP2().getY(),endPoint.getY() + curve.getP3().getY(), t);
                polyline.getPaths().add(  new LatLng(y, x) );
            }
            endPoint = new Point (endPoint.getX() + curve.getP3().getX(), endPoint.getY() + curve.getP3().getY());
        }
        advancedModel.addOverlay(polyline);
        polyline = new Polyline();
    }
}
```

When I don't read any data (don't use readAreas() above) then everything works fine. So how reading from file is connected to this error? I don't understand.

If there is some information that I didn't put here please just say. All these methods run without errors and then this exception is thrown

Comment: Have you checked the total size of the entity that you are trying to put() is?  You are limited to 1MB.

Comment: I don't use Entity because I don't use Datastore. I'm using google cloud sql for database. May be there is something that is using Datastore but is not part of my code for sure. I guess that this Datastore usage is connected with the session somehow. 

So to say there is no put() function in my code

Comment: You should state in the question or tags your using cloudsql. Note cloudsql has a max request and response size of 16MB.  Are you going over that ?

Comment: I don't insert anything into the database. Just read one row from it that is username and password. So 16 MB is far. My hole database is not more than 10 rows and 5 tables. Reading from file has nothing to do with my database. After I read all lines from text file I get the coordinates from them and I draw a poly line on google map. Then I push the logout button and session.removeAttribute("loggedInUser");

Comment: After that I again login using: 1. loggedInUser = UserDAO.getUser(userName, password);   2.Query query = EMF.get().createEntityManager().createQuery("select u from User u where u.email = :email and u.password = :password"); and after login runs drawPolilines() that completes with success and then this error (The request to API call datastore_v3.Put()) is thrown.

Comment: There is one more thing. I'm using primefaces and org.primefaces.model.map.DefaultMapModel; When I create poly line I insert it in this DefaultMapModel (advancedModel in the end of drawPolilines () ). Is it posible that primefaces use the Datastore to save these poly lines and then to draw them on the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See the edit**

Ok. So ... somehow the problem is solved. How? I'm not sure. So I had:

```
a.xhtml  < include b.xhtml 
c.xhtml  < include b.xhtml
a.xhtml and c.xhtml had the same method bFilterMethod()
```

JSF beans:
a, b, c all ViewScoped
b had a and c as Managed Properties
a.xhtml and c.xhtml have bFilterMethod() that getsSome() data from the database and sets aProperty  and cProperty(which are the same). I saw in google app engine logs that the method  getsSome() runs about 20 times like infinite loop after that the exception was thrown.

Now all beans are request scoped

```
a.xhtml has aFilterMethod that getsSome() data
b.xhtml has bFilterMethod that getsSome() data
and a and b has c as Managed Property
```

Hope this helps someone but as I sad I'm not sure what is the exact error but obviously is caused by too big request from the database no matter this request contains only 3 rows (this request is invoked too many times)

**EDIT**
After so many years I came back to my topic accidentally. The real reason for all this is that GAE saves the session in the datastore and jsf ViewScoped beans are not removed from the session as in normal java application server. So the solution is just **don't use ViewScoped beans**